# Will a new GFX card fit?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

Sorry for the ignorance, I know nothing regarding hardware.

I currently have a GTX 770 but want to upgrade it in the near future.
Is it possible to just buy something like a 980 and have it replace the 770? Or is this dependant on the motherboard?

My motherboard is a Gigabyte GA z87 HD3

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: This comes down to your PSU and case. http://superuser.com/questions/304662/what-are-the-things-i-need-to-consider-when-choosing-a-new-graphics-card/304678#304678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its actually more dependant on your case and PSU.

The PCIe x16 *physical* connector is standardised and hasn't changed in years and both cards should fit in the same slot on the motherboard. *Physical* space is an issue, since cards vary in physical length, even with the same connector.

You need to look up two things - the maximum length of card you can fit in your case (or the length of the two cards) and the power needs - both in terms of overall PSU wattage and number/type of power connectors. A 770 is likely to have a single 6 pin connector. A 980 may use a 6+8 pin power connector - you can use an adaptor if needed, and your card may come with it.

If these two conditions are met *any* PCIe video card can be replaced with another

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I currently have a 550w PSU and the 980 has a recommendation of 500w so I assume I am fine in the wattage?

Comment: Actually, the 770 requires 550w PSU so I will be fine. The only thing is that the 980 connectors specifies 2 x 6-pin PCIe and I have no idea what that means. The 770 specifies 1 x 6-pin PCIe 1 x 8-pin PCIe

Comment: Does your power supply have two PCI-E power connectors.  If it does then then you cannot upgrade to the card you are looking at.  Check the manual to the power supply and the video card for more information about installation instructions.

Comment: Ahh. Then it should likely just drop in where your old card was,assuming the case has space. Some manufacturers have longer cards.

Comment: @CarlMarkham you ought to get an adaptor with most cards, or a modular PSU, Pretty sure most cards are 6+8 (My 980Ti is) but getting a extra PCIe 6 pin connector is trivial.